# Logical operations on Java enums

Tags: java, enums, logical-operators

I have a project where, in different scenarios, I have to work on different subsets of a large dataset. The way I have written the code, there is a `Collector` interface, and a class `DataCollector implements Collector`. The class `DataCollector` is instantiated with *the condition of the subset-creation*, and these conditions are enums.

Let's say the dataset is a set of 1 million English words, and I want to work on the subset of words consisting of odd number of letters. Then, I do the following:

```
DataCollector dataCollector = new DataCollector(CollectionType.WORDS_OF_ODD_LENGTH);
Set<String> fourLetteredWords = dataCollector.collect();
```

where `CollectionType` is the enum class

```
enum CollectionType {
    WORDS_OF_ODD_LENGTH,
    WORDS_OF_EVEN_LENGTH,
    STARTING_WITH_VOWEL,
    STARTING_WITH_CONSONANT,
    ....
}
```

The data collector calls a `java.util.Predicate` depending on the enum with which it was instantiated.

So far, this approach has been robust and flexible enough, but now I am facing increasingly complex scenarios (e.g., collect words of even length starting with a vowel). I would like to avoid adding new `CollectionType` for every such scenario. What I have noticed is that many of these complex scenarios are just logical operations on the simpler ones (e.g., `condition_1 && (condition_2 || condition_3)`).

The end-user is the one who specifies these conditions, and the only control I have is that I can specify the set of such conditions. As in, the end-user can only select from `CollectionType`. Right now, I am trying to generalize from the ability to select only one condition to the ability to select one or more. For that, I need something like

```
DataCollector dataCollector = new DataCollector(WORDS_OF_ODD_LENGTH &&
                                                STARTING_WITH_VOWEL);
```

Is there a way I model my enums to carry out such operations? I am open to other ideas (as in, should I just scrap this enum-based approach for something else, etc.).

Comment: What I would do in this case, is to store the different types as `Predicate<String>`, supply one or more of those predicates to the constructor and store them in fields. Then, you could define your subset as all entries which match any of those predicates.

Comment: Guava has a [number of utility functions](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Predicates.html) for composing functions. You could use those to compose your enums. Have your `enum implements Predicate<String>`.

Comment: This is assuming you can use Java 8

Comment: @DennisW the OP mentions `java.util.Predicate`.

Comment: Ah yes! I am using predicates already ... so why not make it `enum implements Predicate<>`? That's so elegant and simple :-)

Comment: @ChthonicProject Honestly? Because I didn't know enums could implement interfaces... That is indeed a better solution, if logically equivalent to what I was trying to suggest.

Comment: Simplicity in coding is a difficult goal to achieve. I am still learning it, and there's  a long way to go. This isn't the first time that Boris made a comment that made me go "uhh ... umm ... oh yes, of course ... wow".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I suggest you use Java 8 which has Predicate and operations supporting predicates.

```
enum CollectionType implements Predicate<String> {
    WORDS_OF_ODD_LENGTH(s -> s.length() % 2 != 0),
    WORDS_OF_EVEN_LENGTH(WORDS_OF_ODD_LENGTH.negate()),
    STARTING_WITH_VOWEL(s -> isVowel(s.charAt(0))),
    STARTING_WITH_CONSONANT(STARTING_WITH_VOWEL.negate()),
    COMPLEX_CHECK(CollectionType::complexCheck);

    private final Predicate<String> predicate;

    CollectionType(Predicate<String> predicate) {
        this.predicate = predicate;
    }

    static boolean isVowel(char c) {
        return "AEIOUaeiou".indexOf(c) >= 0;
    }

    public boolean test(String s) {
        return predicate.test(s);
    }

    public static boolean complexCheck(String s) {
        // many lines of code, calling many methods
    }
}
```

The you can write a Predicate like

```
Predicate<String> p = WORDS_OF_ODD_LENGTH.and(STARTING_WITH_CONSONANT);
```

or even five letter words starting with a vowel

```
Predicate<String> p = STARTING_WITH_VOWEL.and(s -> s.length() == 5);
```

Say you wanted to use this filter on reading the file, you can do

```
List<String> oddWords = Files.lines(path).filter(WORDS_OF_ODD_LENGTH).collect(toList());
```

Or you could index them as you load them with

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> wordsBySize = Files.lines(path)
                                .collect(groupBy(s -> s.length()));
```

Even though you have made your enum is a Predicate you can optimise its usage like this.

```
if (predicate == WORDS_OF_ODD_LENGTH || predicate == WORDS_OF_EVEN_LENGTH) {
    // assume if the first word in a list of words of the same length
    // then take all words of that length.
    return wordsBySize.values().stream()
                               .filter(l -> predicate.test(l.get(0)))
                               .flatMap(l -> l.stream()).collect(toList());
} else {
    return wordsBySize.values().stream()
                               .flatMap(l -> l.stream())
                               .filter(predicate)
                               .collect(toList());
}
```

i.e. by using `enum` you can recognise some predicates and optimise for them. (Whether that is a good idea or not I will leave to you)

Comment: Just one question: my predicates are a *little* more complicated, so I should define them elsewhere just so that the code is readable (e.g., `STARTING_WITH_VOWEL = _startingWithVowel`, where `private static _startingWithVowel = ...` is a 10-15 line code located later). This leads to  the "Illegal forward reference error". Should I create a separate class to hold these predicates, or is there a simple way around it?

Comment: @ChthonicProject You can call a method from a predicate as I did in the example above.  There is no need for the lambda to be more than one line ever (or to use assignment or fields AFAICS)

Comment: Perfect! +1 for adding the `complexCheck` example.

Comment: @ChthonicProject the `complexCheck` doesn't have to be in the same class. Where you put it should be where it makes sense to you.